# Android - как выполнять asynctask с периодичностью 10 секунд

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Всем привет. Не подскажите как мне можно реализовать следующую ситуацию. Нажал я на кнопку "Старт", после чего у меня каждые 10 секунд идёт запрос на json-страницу ну и соответственно парсинг? Ниже указанный код написан с использованием AsyncTask, на Вашем сайте находил похожий вопрос, и в качестве ответа использовать while (true){ }Thread.sleep(3000); К сожалению данную конструкцию так и не удалось строить в своё код..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new ParseTask().execute();
}

private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        String secondName = "";

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends");

            // 1. достаем инфо о втором друге - индекс 1
            JSONObject secondFriend = friends.getJSONObject(1);
            secondName = secondFriend.getString("name");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Второе имя: " + secondName);

            // 2. перебираем и выводим контакты каждого друга
            for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts");

                String phone = contacts.getString("mobile");
                String email = contacts.getString("email");
                String skype = contacts.getString("skype");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "phone: " + phone);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "email: " + email);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "skype: " + skype);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Поллинг со стороны клиента считается не очень хорошей практикой, лучше использовать уведомление пуш-нотификацией со стороны сервера, ну или хотябы сделайте сервис, который будует опрашивать, например https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: Был такой вопрос, найду скину